# Keep a lock on a folder name so it can't be recreated

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an [issue where visual studio keeps recreating a folder after I delete it.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com:80/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/74175e24-9f3f-465c-8216-6e2b099e9df9)

Is there a way to lock a folder name so it can't be created?  (Or somehow block the re-creation of the folder?)

(Note: I don't want to create a file with the same name as the folder.  That leaves me with a file instead of a folder (not much better).)

Comment: How can you lock something that does not exist?

Comment: Not sure.  I was hoping I could "reserve" the folder name then not actually save it...  (A long shot I admit.)

Comment: If you don't want *any* folders to be created within a given parent folder, you could do that with permissions. But that's probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: better add condition if( folder not exists) create folder else nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleted $destinationdirectory$ folder comes back after RunFinished is done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882968/deleted-destinationdirectory-folder-comes-back-after-runfinished-is-done)

Answer (score -1):

How exactly does it re-create folders after you delete it? Is it a glitch, or a problem in the code?

Pseudocode (VB-ish):

```
If ((folder.exists = True) and (folder.empty = True)) Then
 Filesystem.Directory.Remove(Folder)
End If
```

You can just run that in a loop, and if it tries to create a folder, it will just delete it again.

Comment: How does this help me keep it gone?  You psudocode just shows how to delete it.  The hidden folder idea is slightly better, but I still have a folder that I don't want hanging out on the OS.

Comment: Put the psudocode in a loop.
Create a new thread, and just keep running in the loop.

Comment: Alas, the folder is not recreated until after my method exits.